# First columns match; read pattern and replace with specific values in the second file column

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I would like to update file1(tab-delimited) using file2(tab-delimited) conditionally.

For each line of file1, perform the following substitutions for each column except the first, using the line from file2 which has the same value in the first column as the line in file1 has in the first column:

- *a*. If; the field in file1 contain string "A", replace it with string in file2's second column
- *b*. else if; field in file1 contain string "B", replace it with string in file2's third column
- *c*. else; field in file1 with string "X", replace it with string in file2's fourth column

Kindly assist in adding conditions correctly after matching. Thank you in advance.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;next};{print a[$1]}'  file2.txt file1.txt>file3.txt

$ cat replace.awk
{
var1=$2;
var2=$3;
var3=$4;
if ( $0 == "A") $0=var1;
else if ( $0 == "B") $0=var2;
else $0=var3;
print $0,var1,var2,var3;
}
```

Input file1

```
ID  item1   item2   item3   item4 ..
592 A   B   X   B
598 A   B   X   A
612 A   X   A   X
650 A   X   A   B
700 A   X   A   B
822 A   X   A   A
830 A   X   A   A
840 A   X   A   X
```

Input file2

```
ID  var1    var2    var3
568 G   A   NA
570 T   C   NA
592 T   G   NA
598 A   T   NA
612 C   A   NA
650 C   T   NA
700 T   C   NA
822 T   C   NA
830 T   A   NA
840 G   C   NA
900 T   G   NA
1000    A   T   NA
....
```

Expected output

```
ID  item1   item2   item3   item4
592 T   G   NA  G
598 A   T   NA  A
612 C   NA  C   NA
650 C   NA  C   T
700 T   NA  T   C
822 T   NA  T   T
830 T   NA  T   T
840 G   NA  G   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` please try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
    FNR>1 && FNR==NR {a[$1,"A"]=$2; a[$1,"B"]=$3; a[$1,"X"]=$4; next}
    FNR==1 && FNR!=NR {print}
    FNR>1 {for (i=2; i<=5; i++) $i=a[$1,$i]
        print
    }
' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Output:

```
ID      item1   item2   item3   item4
592     T       G       NA      G
598     A       T       NA      A
612     C       NA      C       NA
650     C       NA      C       T
700     T       NA      T       C
822     T       NA      T       T
830     T       NA      T       T
840     G       NA      G       NA
```

**[Explanation]**

- While reading `file2`, it creates a map associating `base` (A, G, T, C or NA)
  with the concatenation of `ID` (568 etc.) and `item` (A, B, or X).
- It prints the 1st line of `file1` as a header line.
- While reading `file1`, it replaces the fields by reading the associative array
  created in the 1st period.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On spot, thank you for your help and explanation. I hope it can handle appx. 1M records well.

Comment: @GlenViet thank you for the reply. I'm also curious if my solution works well with 1M records. If it doesn't, please let me know. I'll try to improve the performance then. BR.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -e'
```

```perl
    my %file2;
    {
       my $file2_qfn = shift(@ARGV);
       open(my $fh2, "<", $file2_qfn)
          or die("Can't open \"$file2_qfn\": $!\n");

       if (<$fh2>) {  # Skip header.
          while (<$fh2>) {
             chomp;
             my @fields = split /\t/;
             $file2{$fields[0]} = \@fields;
          }
       }
    }

    while (<>) {
       if ($. == 1) {  # Handle header.
          print;
          next;
       }

       chomp;
       my @fields = split /\t/;
       if ( my $changes = $file2{$fields[0]} ) {
          for (@fields[1..$#fields]) {
             if    ($_ eq "A") { $_ = $changes->[1]; }
             elsif ($_ eq "B") { $_ = $changes->[2]; }
             elsif ($_ eq "X") { $_ = $changes->[3]; }
          }
       }

       print(join("\t", @fields), "\n");
    }
```

```
' file2.tsv file1.tsv
```

The above loads the entirety of file2 into memory, but that can easily be avoided if the two files are sorted by the first column.

```
perl -e'
```

```perl
    sub get_row {
       my ($fh) = @_;
       defined( my $line = <$fh> )
          or return undef;

       chomp($line);
       return [ split /\t/, $line ];
    }

    sub print_row { print(join("\t", @_), "\n"); }

    my $file2_qfn = shift(@ARGV);
    open(my $fh2, "<", $file2_qfn)
       or die("Can't open \"$file2_qfn\": $!\n");

    my $fh1 = \*ARGV;

    my $row1 = get_row($fh1);
    if ($row1) {  # Handle header.
       print_row(@$row1);
       $row1 = get_row($fh1);
    }

    my $row2 = get_row($fh2);
    $row2 = get_row($fh2) if $row2;  # Skip header.

    while ($row1 && $row2) {
       my $cmp = $row1->[0] <=> $row2->[0];
       if ($cmp <= 0) {
          if ($cmp == 0) {
             for (@$row1[1..$#$row1]) {
                if    ($_ eq "A") { $_ = $row2->[1]; }
                elsif ($_ eq "B") { $_ = $row2->[2]; }
                elsif ($_ eq "X") { $_ = $row2->[3]; }
             }
          }

          print_row(@$row1);
       }

       $row1 = get_row($fh1) if $cmp <= 0;
       $row2 = get_row($fh2) if $cmp >= 0;
    }

    while ($row1) {
       print_row(@$row1);
       $row1 = get_row($fh1);
    }
```

```
' file2.tsv file1.tsv
```

---

Usage (both versions):

```
perl -e'...' -i~ file2.tsv file1.tsv        # Modifies named file in place with backup.
perl -e'...' -i file2.tsv file1.tsv         # Modifies named file in place without backup.
perl -e'...' file2.tsv file1.tsv >out.tsv   # Reads from named file, outputs to STDOUT.
```

Comment: I appreciate your help in framing my question appropriately. I seem not to get the program execute well. Saved and run using:  `perl swap_projected_vcf.pl file2.tsv file1.tsv`..it outputs the original input files in both cases. Please let me know if am doing it wrong.

Comment: @Glen Viet, Found problems and fixed them. Tested.

Comment: @ ikegami, perfect. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code for explanation

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# USAGE:
#   prog.pl -a fileA -b fileB
#
# Description:
#   Demonstration code for StackOverflow Q59942022
#
# Parameters:
#   -a,--filea  input file with pattern to substitudes
#   -b,--fileb  input file with values for substitution
#   -d,--debug  debug flag
#   -h,--help   brief help message
#   --man       manual page with more details
#
# StackOverflow: 
#   Question 59942022
#
# Author:
#   Polar Bear
#
# Date: Tue Jan 28 3:09:00 PST 2020
#

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage;
use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my $fh;         # file handler
my %opt;        # command line options
my %data;       # fileA data storage
my %fileb;      # fileB data storage
my @order;      # to keep line order

GetOptions(
        'filea|a=s'     => \$opt{data},
        'fileb|b=s'     => \$opt{fileb},
        'debug|d'       => \$opt{debug},
        'help|?'        => \$opt{help},
        'man'           => \$opt{man}
) or pod2usage(2);

pod2usage(1) if $opt{help};
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2) if $opt{man};

print Dumper(\%opt) if $opt{debug};

open $fh, '<', $opt{data}
        or die "Couldn't open $opt{data}";

map {                                   # process fileA (pattern)
    chomp;
    my @a = split /\t/; 
    push @order, $a[0];                 # preserve line order
    push @{$data{$a[0]}}, @a[1..$#a]
} <$fh>;

close $fh;

open $fh, '<', $opt{fileb}
        or die "Couldn't open $opt{fileb}";

map {                                   # process fileB (values)
    chomp;
    my @a = split /\t/;
    push @{$fileb{$a[0]}}, @a[1..$#a];
} <$fh>;

close $fh;

say Dumper(\%data)  if $debug;
say Dumper(\%fileb) if $debug;

foreach my $k ( @order ) {              # make required substitution
    if( defined $fileb{$k} ) {
        foreach my $i (0..$#{$data{$k}}) {
            $data{$k}[$i] = $fileb{$k}[0] if $data{$k}[$i] eq 'A';
            $data{$k}[$i] = $fileb{$k}[1] if $data{$k}[$i] eq 'B';
            $data{$k}[$i] = $fileb{$k}[2] if $data{$k}[$i] eq 'X';
        }
    }
    say join "\t", $k, @{$data{$k}};    # output result to console
} 

__END__

=head1 NAME

program - describe program's functionality 

=head1 SYNOPSIS

program.pl [options]

 Options:
    -a,--filea  fileA input filename
    -b,--fileb  fileB input filename
    -d,--debug  output debug information
    -?,--help   brief help message
       --man    full documentation

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item B<-a,--filea>

FileA input filename

=item B<-b,--fileb>

FileB input filename

=item B<-d,--debug>

Print debug information.

=item B<-?,--help>

Print a brief help message and exits.

=item B<--man>

Prints the manual page and exits.

=back

B<This program> reads two input files and substitudes values in first file
according predefined rules: A - second column, B - third column, X - forth column

=cut
```

Input FileA

```
ID  item1   item2   item3   item4 ..
592 A   B   X   B
598 A   B   X   A
612 A   X   A   X
650 A   X   A   B
700 A   X   A   B
822 A   X   A   A
830 A   X   A   A
840 A   X   A   X
```

Input FileB

```
ID  var1    var2    var3
568 G   A   NA
570 T   C   NA
592 T   G   NA
598 A   T   NA
612 C   A   NA
650 C   T   NA
700 T   C   NA
822 T   C   NA
830 T   A   NA
840 G   C   NA
900 T   G   NA
1000    A   T   NA
```

Output

```
ID      item1   item2   item3   item4 ..
592     T       G       NA      G
598     A       T       NA      A
612     C       NA      C       NA
650     C       NA      C       T
700     T       NA      T       C
822     T       NA      T       T
830     T       NA      T       T
840     G       NA      G       NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It executes fine for now.